# Como adicionar um elemento no final de uma lista ligada

Tags: c++, lista, lista-encadeada

Preciso adicionar um elemento no final de uma lista ligada, fiz o método pedindo para ele adicionar como se ele fosse um elemento inicial caso a lista esteja vazia (está funcionando) e, caso não esteja, percorrendo a lista da seguinte forma:

```
else{
    Celula * cursor = prim;
    while (cursor != NULL){
      cursor = cursor -> getProx();
```

Para mim, quando ele chega na condição de parada, é porque o cursor = NULL, criando outra condição para adicionar o elemento que seria a seguinte:

```
if (cursor == NULL){
  Celula * c = new Celula(i);
  c->setProx(prim);
  cout << cursor->getInfo()<< endl;
```

Quando rodo o programa, eu consigo inserir o primeiro elemento normalmente, mas quando vou inserir no final, o programa quebra.

Caso alguém precise do programa full para entender melhor (desculpe se não sou bom com palavras rs), segue o link do arquivo no repl.it cujo problema está em ListaLigada.cpp

https://repl.it/@RodrigoCosta1/beijonabocaecoisadopassadoagramodaefazerlistaligada

(ignorem o título do link)

Comment: Se para em `NULL` ao fazer `->` qualquer coisa sobre `NULL` vai crashar. Troque a condição do `while` para `while (cursor->getProx() != NULL){`

Comment: Troquei e ele não crashou, mas mesmo assim não está adicionando nada do final.

Comment: Isso já tem a ver com a parte de definir o próximo. Olhando para o seu código e sem testar seria algo como a seguir ao `while`, fazer `Celula * c = new Celula(i);c->setProx(NULL);cursor->setProx(c);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não está adicionando os itens nos final, está apontando todos os novos itens para o primeiro.

Você deve criar um novo item e apontar o ultimo da lista para ele, assim:

```
while (cursor->getProx() != NULL)
    cursor = cursor->getProx();

if (cursor->getProx() == NULL)
{
    Celula * c = new Celula(i);

    //  Aponta o ultimo item encontrado para o novo item.
    cursor->setProx(c); 
}
```